# Create all possible combinations using a deque and recursion C++

Tags: c++, recursion

I have a deque that contains a series of numbers `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}` and I am trying to create all possible combinations of these numbers using recursion.

Here is my current code

```
void combination(vector<node> &comb, deque<node> &numbers) {

    if (numbers.empty()) {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < comb.size(); i++) {
            cout << comb[i].id << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
        return;
    }

    comb.push_back(numbers.front());
    numbers.pop_front();
    combination(comb, numbers);
    comb.pop_back();
    combination(comb, numbers);
}
```

I've ran this through on paper and it makes sense but when I run it this is the output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6
0 1 2 3 4 5
0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3
0 1 2
0 1
0
```

Why isn't the function printing out all possible combinations?

Also, this is what I want to use - A deque that contains the numbers and a vector that contains each combination.

Comment: I assume this is for a school exercise or other learning experience? Otherwise you should be using [`std::next_permutation`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) instead.

Comment: I'm using this to implement a Branch and Bound method for a problem. So, I can not use `next_permutation`

Comment: Also, the code as you've posted here, would not compile. I assume the function should be called `permute` instead of `combination` and `combination.push_back(...)` should be `comb.push_back(...)`?

Comment: @CantrianBear Not a helpful answer. There would be no point to this website if that was the case. I clearly don't know why it's not performing how I expected and this is a last resort.

Comment: You're passing `numbers` by reference. On the first leaf reached, it gets empty() for good.

Comment: @O'Neil worked like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Pass by reference, i have made some minor changes and it works

code :

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void combination(vector<int> comb, deque<int> numbers) {

    if (numbers.empty()) {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < comb.size(); i++) {
            cout << comb[i] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
        return;
    }

    comb.push_back(numbers.front());
    numbers.pop_front();
    combination(comb, numbers);
    comb.pop_back();
    combination(comb, numbers);
}

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    vector<int> comb;
    deque<int> numbers;
    for(int i = 0;i < 7;i++) numbers.push_back(i);
    combination(comb, numbers);
    return 0;
}
```

Link to solution on ideone : http://ideone.com/vgukF3

Comment: Someone else has commented on my post that only the deque needs to be pass by value but this is also a good answer.